# More impressive way of saying "I am really interested in your works" to a Prof

Tags: british-english

I want to send an email to a professor in London. I wanna say "I'm really interested n your works" but I am searching for a more impressive and more British way of saying that. Could any one help me?

Comment: Avoid asking for help writing (or proofreading). “How should I write this?”, “is this correct?”, and “which is correct?” questions are out of scope and your question may be removed. See: “[What topics can I ask about here? - Help Center](/help/on-topic)”. If there is an unstated specific concern, such as “What does (word) mean in context?” or “How does (grammar or punctuation rule) apply in context?” ask that question instead. Also check out “[Where can I ask for free proofreading? – Meta](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7571)”

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could write something like:

> Dear Professor Surname,
>
> I was enthralled and impressed by your remarkable and groundbreaking work on the tubular endothrums of reticulate worms.

But here's my advice: **don't**.

I don't know where you are from, but I have seen many students from countries such as India write emails to British scientists which are much too floral and seem positively cringeworthy to the usually casual British ear. The professor you are writing to is unlikely to want to see you bow and scrape, and will be unimpressed by extravagant language use. Instead they want to know *why* you find it interesting and *what* it is you are writing to them for. A clear, concise email is much more likely to get a positive response than one which goes for "impressive" language.

So instead write something like this:

> Dear Professor Surname,
>
> I am writing to you to express my interest in your advertised project 'sexual signalling in retriculate worms'.
>
> While studying for my Masters degree at the University of Place, I came across your 2016 paper "Rethinking the endothrum". I was particularly interested in your idea that rather than being involved solely in immune resistance, endothrums are used as a device for sexual signalling. This was exciting for me because during my research project on non-reticulate worms.... (etc.)

Which shows you've read their work, explains why you're interested in it, and links it to your work and/or background. I've arbitrarily assumed that you're a student looking for a position, but if you're interested in collaboration or just in discussing their ideas the same applies. Put your efforts into explaining why they should spend their time on you, not on tarting up your language.

Comment: I usually downvote answers to questions like this in order that people get discouraged from answering such questions, and lacking answers, people get discouraged from asking such questions in the first place. But this is such solid advice, I'll recuse myself from this thread. Well done.

Comment: @Dan Bron: It struck me that this question (and the answer) belongs squarely to https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/ or maybe academia.SE, but in either case, the culturally cued response seems good to me.

Comment: Great answer ... but I'm not sure I'll ever be able to put a worm on a hook again when I next go fishing, after reading this.

Comment: I'd give this two upvotes if I could!